# Duplicate rows with no primary key keep 1 row postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is THE way to remove completely identical rows from a table with 2 columns and keep 1 row? (DISTINCT only works on 1 column)

```
Var1 Var2 
1    a
1    a
1    a
2    a
2    b
```

Desired output table

```
Var1 Var2
1    a
2    a
2    b
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` works on the whole selected rows. Simply try it, and you'll see.

Comment: `DISTINCT` always operator on **all** columns in the select list. It's a common misconception that it only applies to the column following the keyword.

Comment: You are right, so distinct does not work on ONE column then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT var1,var2 FROM tabel_name
```

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT DISTINCT var1, var2  FROM tablename`???

Comment: Here is no difference, but in general `SELECT DISTINCT` eliminates duplicate rows from the result. `SELECT DISTINCT ON` eliminates rows that match on all the specified expressions. `SELECT ALL` (the default) will return all candidate rows, including duplicates

Comment: I'd just keep it simple.